# Will NPM init fail on my local machine if nodejs is an older version?

Tags: node.js

Hi all I was having this issue today where I could not use npm -v or npm init, even though it was working with no issues weeks ago. It kept giving me this throw error but I closed my cmd and dont have it anymore.

I uninstalled and reinstalled and it fixed the issue, but am scared if this occurs again in the future, especially if I have put in a lot of effort into a proejct.

Comment: Ask here when the issues occurs again, allowing you to provide either the error message or a way to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Will do, thanks vince